# Restrict rows based on a join table, using a count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a employee table, and a vacations table where each row represents a day they took for vacation.

I want to get all employees who have taken more vacation days that their maximum vacation days value.

```
employees:
employeeId
maxVacationDays

vacations:
employeeId
date_vacation_day_taken
```

Query I have now:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employees e
         INNER JOIN vacations v ON (v.employeeId = e.employeeId)
WHERE e.isActive = true AND ( ???? > e.maxVacationDays)
```

So I need to get the count of rows from the vacations table for that employeeId.

Do I need a subquery for this?

(using sql2000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.employeeId, v.maxVacationDays
FROM employees e
         INNER JOIN vacations v ON (v.employeeId = e.employeeId)
WHERE e.isActive = true
GROUP BY e.employeeId, v.maxVacationDays
HAVING COUNT(v.employeeId) > v.maxVacationDays
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId
        ,COUNT(v.date_vacation_day_taken) TotalDaysTaken
        ,e.maxVacationDays MaxDaysAllowed
FROM Employees e
    INNER JOIN vacations v 
        ON v.employeeId = e.employeeId
WHERE e.isactive = true
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId, e.maxVacationDays, e.isactive
HAVING COUNT(v.date_vacation_day_taken) > e.maxVacationDays
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT e.employeeId, e.maxVacationDays, 
           SUM(v.date_vacation_day_taken) 'dayscount'
    FROM employees e
    INNER JOIN vacations v ON (v.employeeId = e.employeeId)
    GROUP BY e.employeeId, e.maxVacationDays
    WHERE e.isactive = true
) sub
WHERE sub.dayscount > e.maxVacationDays)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
select e.employeeId, e.maxVacationDays, count(v.*) as vacationDaysTaken
from employees e
    join vacations v on e.employeeId = v.employeeId
group by e.employeeId, e.maxVacationDays
having e.maxVacationDays < count(v.*)
```